# Zf2 Getting list of time zone drop down

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Hello I have i want to dispaly time zone drop down in my layout page... Is there any method in zf2 to get time zone list or it may be do manually database entry and getting this list.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, but there is in PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-identifiers-list.php

For IANA format strings (e.g. Europe/London, America/New_York):

```
DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers()
```

or

```
timezone_identifiers_list()
```

And for abbreviations:

```
DateTimeZone::listAbbreviations()
```

or

```
timezone_abbreviations_list()
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-abbreviations-list.php

Comment: Is there any way in php i get time zone list as like window pc.

Comment: I would suggest creating a mapping between the IANA format list and however you want to display them. I'd also suggest just picking out the ones you want/need to support.